# Built Angular web app. Unexpected border alignment shift when comparing two different web pages

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I've successfully followed a MEAN stack tutorial and now I'm learning about how to format the web pages using .css and .html.

Specifically, I've created 1. Home page 2. Contact page 3. Data collection page (uses angular forms, etc.) as Angular components which encompasses the use of three .ts components (a/"base form" b/"add" c/"edit"). Within these .ts files I've correctly defined the @Component to call the templateUrl and styleUrls.

I've added a "navigation" menu bar component and incorporated it into the html pages representing all three primary .ts.

The .css and .html I've used across all 3 pages are consistent; padding, etc.. Everything "functionally" works - there are no errors being thrown. Visually everything looks nice. The navigation menu bar shows up where I want it to (at the top of each page).

However, on the Data collection page, the navigation menu bar and the form in the body shift ever so slightly a few pixels to the right.

I've checked the .css and .html for add.component.ts; edit.component.ts; data-form.component.ts; home.component.ts; navigation.component.ts and I've tinkered to the point where nothing is correcting. I've tried "inherit", I've tried "encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation". I've added, removed lines of code to test things out.

Good news is I was able to zero in on the HTML code that, when I delete it, the alignment issue goes away, meaning, the navigation menu on the data page becomes consistently aligned with the other navigation menu placements on the other web pages. So the data collection form itself seems to be causing the slight shift. By the way, the shift is merely horizontal - the vertical "distance" appears to be good-to-go.

This is the block of code that is causing the formatting shift.

```
<h1>Data Form</h1>
<div class="content">
<app-data-form (formSubmitted)="addData($event)"></app-data-form>
</div>
```

My question is, where do I turn next for troubleshooting?